# Sidebar width not changing in Google sheet using Google apps script

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script

Sidebar width not changing in Google sheet using Google apps script

```
function onOpen()
{
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('side').setTitle('Custom sidebar').setWidth(150);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(html);
}
```

This is the sheet , code is in Tools>script editor of this sheet.
    https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1hCOU5mUQxaXRz6JTyO6IZphVkfiii1RS5OsLhMJWFNY/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 4):

In Google Docs and Forms, sidebars now ignore the setWidth() method; they cannot be changed from the default width of 300px. This change was applied to the new version of Sheets in the previous week's release.

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/releases/#february_2014

Comment: Thanks @OblongMedulla